# HIbernate show_sql development only

Tags: java, hibernate

With hibernate how can i enable show_sql in development mode only?
I want that
`<property name="show_sql">true</property>` be disabled for production and enabled for development environment.

Comment: Do you use any deployment script like `ant`?

Comment: Check this link.. I think you will find most of the information.
[Connect different database dev-test-production][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738560/how-to-connect-to-different-databases-development-test-production-transparentl

Comment: How do you make anything different in development versus production?  Seriously, how are you doing it? Because your answer needs to be compatible with that and ideally should be done the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be keeping environmental related information in a separate **properties** file. This file should be read from your **hibernate.cfg.xml** or **applicationContext.xml**.

Here is sample file

```
###########################################################
################DATABASE INFORMATION ######################
###########################################################
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/appDB1
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root


# Set Hibernate properties
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=false
```

Similarly you can add more configuration information. This file will be different in different environments.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also tell me how to read and parse this properties file?

Comment: @PratikKhadloya: are you using spring?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming from your question that being "in development mode" is something that your code knows at runtime, because otherwise you would simply change the flag in the configuration file.

In that case, you can set the show_sql property (or any other property) programmatically at runtime:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setProperty(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
config.buildSessionFactory();
...
```

then you just need to select true/false based on your state that indicates that you're in development mode or not.

Comment: From http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html : "The Configuration is meant only as an initialization-time object. SessionFactorys are immutable and do not retain any association back to the Configuration." So the change can only be made at application startup, not after the session was created.