# EJB, settings.ini file

Tags: java, file, ejb, settings, ini

I need any solution to provide settings for Enterprise Java Bean without recompilation. For example - DB server ip, DB server user-login, any other app settings.

For example - in php we may create settings.ini file. We may edit this file whenever we want. Every time script launched - this file parsed and new settings applied.

I need smth like this for EJB. Given the specificity of EJB I think there may be two options:

1. we will do smth and needed settings appear in application server (Glassfish) control panel as settings for our bean. Every time settings changed appServer relaunch bean (clear pool, etc.) and after that new settings applied.
2. we create myEJB.war file and additional file settings.ini. Every time bean redeployed - new settings from settings.ini applied

Do we have any way to set up application?

Comment: I think this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450297/how-to-access-deployment-parameter-from-within-ejb

Comment: JNDI is the key technology here [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7738736/682559) might be helpful.